# The number of configurations Keras Hyperband gives me per round doesn't match the code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, training-data, hyperparameters

I'm trying to figure out how the Keras implementation of Hyperband calculates the number of configurations to test per round within a bracket. When I run Keras Hyperband with max_epochs=10 and factor=2 and look at the output, this is what I get:

[image: Run Table]

Where s = bracket number, i = round number, n = number of configurations tested in round i, ri = number of epochs each of those configurations get in round i.

However, when we look at the source code (https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/0dd114dd5353c941e8e14e68356a3fb124e3a0d1/keras_tuner/tuners/hyperband.py#L23), it seems to me that we should instead have:

[image: Code Table]

In particular, I'm looking at the functions,

```
def _get_size(self, bracket_num, round_num):
    # Set up so that each bracket takes approx. the same amount of
    # resources.
    bracket0_end_size = math.ceil(
        1 + math.log(self.max_epochs, self.factor)
    )
    bracket_end_size = bracket0_end_size / (bracket_num + 1)
    return math.ceil(
        bracket_end_size * self.factor ** (bracket_num - round_num)
    )

def _get_epochs(self, bracket_num, round_num):
    return math.ceil(
        self.max_epochs / self.factor ** (bracket_num - round_num)
    )

def _get_num_rounds(self, bracket_num):
    # Bracket 0 just runs random search, others do successive halving.
    return bracket_num + 1

def _get_num_brackets(self):
    epochs = self.max_epochs
    brackets = 0
    while epochs >= self.min_epochs:
        epochs = epochs / self.factor
        brackets += 1
    return brackets
```

and assuming that get_size is getting the number of configurations in that bracket and that round.

Am I just making some really silly calculations? Why is my model getting slightly different numbers of configurations, but the same number of epochs? (For reference, I had 5 different hyper parameters, each with 2 options, so 32 possible configurations available to test, and I used an early stopping callback with a patience of 8, though I doubt it came into effect here.)

I've tried running with several different values of max_epochs and factor, and I can only seem to get it the same if there are a very small number of brackets (everything goes kind of wonk once you get up to the s=3 bracket).